# Show index.html when they go to /admin/*

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking for a solutions for the following:

When they go to s**ubdomain.domain.be** or **subdomain.domain.be/admin** or **subdomain.domain.be/admin/something** I want them to see the **index.html in the root of my subdomain**.

How can I do this with **htaccess**?

I've tried this in my .htaccess: `Redirect 301 /admin/* /index.html` . But that doesn't do anything. Also tried this: `Redirect 301 /admin/* /index.html` but then I get **index.htmlsomething** ...

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/(*.)$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Are you saying you want `domain.be` to redirect to `subdomain`, and so on? Or that you are already on `subdomain`.

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` entry of `subdomain.domain.be`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.be$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R]
```

Comment: I still get the error: The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.

Comment: what url are you going to? is mod_rewrite active on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`RewriteRule ^admin/(*.)$ /index.html [L]`

And see the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Put `index.html` in the root of `subdomain.domain.be` and it should display automatically.

If not, try `DirectoryIndex index.html`.

Comment: When I try the first I get a 500 internal server error. The second doesn't work with /admin .. updated my topic with htaccess content